Run Eclipse Scout Project without Intellij or Eclipse?
Is there a way to run an Eclipse Scout project without Intellij or Eclipse?
If you create the JAR files with mvn install, there should be a way to run these JARs in the Windows CMD console. Unfortunately the usual method with jar -cp does not work.

I assume your using Scout >= 24.1? Then have a look at Build Scout App and Run as Service. That explains how to use the build output of the .app.zip module to run as a service, but same applies to just start the application via bash script (chapter Unzip & Run).
If your using Scout < 24.1, .war files are the outputs, which can be run within a Tomcat or local Jetty.
